# Refresh UI language on the fly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm following this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) to localize my app. I don't want to get system language so I don't use `ILocalize` interface and dependecy services. I have these 3 resx files for English, Spanish and French languages:

- AppResources.es.resx
- AppResources.fr.resx
- AppResources.resx (English)

This is my `TestPage.xaml` code using `TranslateExtension` class from guide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:LanguageTest.Resources;assembly=LanguageTest.Resources"
             x:Class="LanguageTest.TestPage">
    <Label Text="{t:Translate TestText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

With this code I initilize language settings:

```
public App ()
{
    // I can change among "en", "es" and "fr"
    AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("es"); 
    this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());
}
```

I this case the texts are displayed in Spanish. But I want to change the language after the pages are displayed (for example, using a `LanguageSettingsPage` the user can change the language while the app is running).

```
public App ()
{
    AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("es"); 
    this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());
    AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("fr");
    // At this point the texts are diplayed in Spanish, not in French
}
```

How can I refresh de page to display French texts without doing `new TestPage()` again?

Comment: did you find solution for that? can you please share if yes?

Comment: @batmaci No, I did't find the solution. When a language is selected I change all the texts from App.cs code. There is no system that allow you to change the texts using bindings or something similar.

Comment: to redisplay the main page you can do `MainPage = new NavigationPage(...);`

Answer (score 1):

this is not an specific solution for Resx, but it will let you load any language on user demand. No need to set strings manually as bindings will do the job. Take a look at [I18NPortable](https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable) and the samples. It´s pretty easy to get it up and running.

Binding sample:

```
<Button Text="{Binding Strings[key]}" />
```

To change the language on the fly (will update all the bindings):

```
I18N.Current.Locale = "fr";
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the Setters for the Text property on the OnAppearing() method,then after coming back from the settings page, it will take the latest values from the resx file. The OnAppearing() method will be invoked even when you are coming back to a page.
But for the same page to change language to have to either render the page again or reload the Text property of the elements in that page.

Comment: But in this case you are writing code behind to change the view, I want to avoid that.

Comment: Same can be done in viewmodel if that is what you are looking for. VM will have an init method.

Comment: I think that the previous code behind option is better and cleaner than the VM option. But this kind of solution is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply popping the page, the resources will not be evaluated again. You are simply being displayed the previous page on your nav stack (still in the memory).

You need to push a new page for new resource texts to be loaded.

Comment: how do you push a new page for main page without exiting and re-entering the app?

Comment: Your stack will maintain one main/home page which will be the first item of your stack. For that main/home page, you need to change the resources in code behind i.e. without binding. (this is one limitation.) The moment you change the locale, you can pop to root. This is the approach which i have also used in my case. Let me know, if it's not clear for you.

Comment: Yes you have to change the texts from code behind. In WPF I used ObjectDataProvider, but there is no anything similar to it in Xamarin.

Comment: Yes, this is the only limitation that we need to change it in code behind for one page. In fact, i have used the same in ActionScript with data binding and there is no need to change manually.Hope we will find anything more in future in XF.